“I find garish clothes ______” I want to fill in the blank with an adjective/phrase that means “unpleasant to look at”

I find garish clothes ______”

I want to fill in the blank with an adjective/phrase that means “unpleasant to look at”
I found some suggestions which are visually jarring, like an eye sore, off-putting to look at, which one is the best? If none is acceptable, could you suggest me a better one?
(You might wonder why I didn’t simply use “unpleasant to look at”, that’s because I want to paraphrase it in different ways)

The word "garish" already conveys your disapproval. But, sticking with your structure, you might use "ugly" or "repellent".

Something unpleasant to look at is 'an eyesore', not 'like' one.

There is no best, and I don't understand a question like this: I find loud music obnoxioius. So, what do you make of that?

@Lambie "obnoxioius"?
